# How to get Text from a div element returns just a "." with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a div element which looks like below.

[image]

I identify this element with the following xpath.

```
//*[contains(@class,'ce-component-title')]
```

Selenium identifies this element and loads the WebElement object. But when I go to get its text, I'm just getting a "." as shown below instead of getting "Purchase to pay process". What am I doing wrong here? I checked the chrome console and there's no other element matching this xpath.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML you have shared the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  String myString = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div[ng-if*='getTitle']>div.ce-component-title"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  String myString = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@ng-if,'getTitle')]/div[@class='ce-component-title flex text-overflow ng-binding']"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Deb. If the element is not visible, I would get an element not found exception right? I have the element in my WebElement object. Just that the get text method returns a ".".

Comment: Nopes, if the element is not visible you would get _ElementNotVisible_ exception. How about the solution? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think your xpath (//*[contains(@class,'ce-component-title')]) returns more than one element, and the element you need is not the first one.
Try using console of your browser, to verify how many elements this xpath returns.
I can help you if you give me url to this page.